# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. react-native

Tags: react-native

Could not find the "expo" package in your project when configuring the packager
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   /media/rahul/OTHER FILES/mob/first/android/app/src/main/java/com/practice/MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
>   import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
>                            ^
>     symbol:   class ReactApplication
>     location: package com.facebook.react
>   /media/rahul/OTHER FILES/mob/first/android/app/src/main/java/com/practice/MainApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
>   import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
>                            ^
>     symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
>     location: package com.facebook.react
>   /media/rahul/OTHER FILES/mob/first/android/app/src/main/java/com/practice/MainApplication.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
>   public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
>                                                               ^
>     symbol: class ReactApplication
>   /media/rahul/OTHER FILES/mob/first/android/app/src/main/java/com/practice/MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>     private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
>                   ^
>     symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
>     location: class MainApplication
>   /media/rahul/OTHER FILES/mob/first/android/app/src/main/java/com/practice/MainApplication.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
>     public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
>            ^
>     symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
>     location: class MainApplication
>   /media/rahul/OTHER FILES/mob/first/android/app/src/main/java/com/practice/MainActivity.java:5: error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPackages() in ReactActivity
>   public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
>          ^
>   /media/rahul/OTHER FILES/mob/first/android/app/src/main/java/com/practice/MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>     private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
>                                                          ^
>     symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
>     location: class MainApplication
>   /media/rahul/OTHER FILES/mob/first/android/app/src/main/java/com/practice/MainApplication.java:35: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>     @Override
>     ^
>   8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
15 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 1 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

i am setting up react-native project for first time please check if i am following steps correctly?
 1. create-react-native-app first
 2. npm run eject
 3. opening android studio and then simulator
 4. react-native run-android
but getting error as above.

Comment: So, scroll up to see more details. Or run it with one of those flags like it recommends

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This error occur because you RN version is different from Android's build.gradle version. When you create a react-native app probably it create android app like:

```
android/app/build.gradle

implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

So, inspect you node_modules folder, look for react-native folder and look for a folder with a number, that numbers are react-native version. For me it's 0.58.3 then update **android/app/build.gradle**:

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.3"
```

It's All.

Comment: "look for a folder with a number" - do you mean get the version number from package.json? ..this didnt work for me

Comment: I think he is talking about : "project_folder\node_modules\react-native\android\com\facebook\react\react-native\", there I found a folder with numbers... I tried this, but it was not the solution for my case

Comment: You can also look at your package.json for you react-native version

Comment: Why does your solution work?

Answer (score 13):

If you are here because of this React Native error:

```
> Task :react-native-community_toolbar-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

The solution is updating the **@react-native-community/toolbar-android** to version **0.2.1**

Answer (score 10):

You should provide more info. The error you've posted is not very helpful.

Without more info, you could try to:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: I went to he project folder in command line and pasted this command.
It says it does not recognize the . command as internal or external command.

Can you please provide some more detail how did you resolve this?

Comment: try gradlew clean

Comment: not helping, tried many times

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I ended here googling my similar compile problem and the issue was that an OS update had wiped Java JDK from my path. Fixing that solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar crash report. But in my case the issue was a missing environment variable for `JAVA_HOME`.
I set it to the same path as in Android Studio and that fixed the issue: File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK location.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: It helped me. But in Android Studio 2023 you need to go to "Android Studio -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment, Build Tools, Gradle -> <your project> -> Gradle JDK"

Answer (score 2):

[For people who are brought here by Google]

In my case, the error appeared after I try to link `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` using `react-native link`.

I initialized my project using React Native CLI, which was a few minor versions behind. But I linked the dependency with `npx react-native link`. **Version Mismatch!**

To the best of my knowledge, this is the root cause of that error.

You are most likely to make changes inside `android/app/src/main/java/com/focustime/MainApplication.java` and `android/settings.gradle`.
If you are developing with `git`, simply `checkout` those two files.

Following are the changes that `RN link` introduced:

```
diff --git a/android/app/src/main/java/com/focustime/MainApplication.java b/android/app/src/main/java/com/focustime/MainApplication.java
index ed18f44..2bdc42c 100644
--- a/android/app/src/main/java/com/focustime/MainApplication.java
+++ b/android/app/src/main/java/com/focustime/MainApplication.java
@@ -4,6 +4,7 @@ import android.app.Application;
 import android.content.Context;
 import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
 import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
+import com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncStoragePackage;
 import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
 import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
 import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
diff --git a/android/settings.gradle b/android/settings.gradle
index 20ccd07..f6f51cd 100644
--- a/android/settings.gradle
+++ b/android/settings.gradle
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
 rootProject.name = 'FocusTime'
+include ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage'
+project(':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android')
 apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
 include ':app'
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me because I forget to install some modules.

### And I run:

## 1. `npm install`

## 2. `npx react-native run-android`

OBS: you can run `npx react-native link` too. To link your modules.

Comment: `npx react-native link` doesn't work on RN version 0.73.x : `error: unknown command 'link'`

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times this is due the Configuration of the ANDROID_HOME is not done properly. And other times this due the gradle version miss-match

if you are using zsh which is default for newer Mac
open terminal and type these commands

`nano ~/.zshrc or vim ~/.zshrc`

and paste these three lines

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

save the file and then run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

close the terminal fully and run your emulator

Answer (score 1):

In my case

My React native version is **`0.62.2`**

and

```
    buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

so I just update the `compiledSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`

```
    buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

Android 13 support the compiledSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion should be changed to 33

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by
first check your all JAVA Environment variables are properly set or not
otherwise set:

```
>  JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
>          JDK_HOME  : %JAVA_HOME%
>          JRE_HOME  : %JAVA_HOME%\jre
>          CLASSPATH : .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
>          PATH      : ....;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

then I added jdk path:

> org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.x.x

to `gradle.properties`

Finally, I've ran in the terminal:

```
cd android &&./gradlew clean
cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this issue in my React Native project, I did some useful steps. Follow them as:

1. In my terminal, move to the android folder by typing **cd android**
2. Then type **./gradlew clean**. It will take 1 min approx.
3. Return back to root folder by typing **.. cd**
4. Run this command to rebuilt **npx react-native run-android**