# Unable To Create Build in React Native.react-native-appearance:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, build.gradle

Below Error Is Coming: It Looks Like react native is not able to find any library. This Error is at the time of development. when i tried to run the development server, it got failed with react-native-appearance:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error.

```
 Task :react-native-appearance:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
17 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 11 up-to-date
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:14: error: package com.facebook.common.logging does not exist
import com.facebook.common.logging.FLog;
                                  ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:15: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
                                ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:16: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.LifecycleEventListener;
                                ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:17: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
                                ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:18: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
                                ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:19: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
                                ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:20: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
                                ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:21: error: package com.facebook.react.common does not exist
import com.facebook.react.common.ReactConstants;
                                ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:22: error: package com.facebook.react.modules.core does not exist
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
                                      ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
public class RNCAppearanceModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventListener {
                                         ^
  symbol: class ReactContextBaseJavaModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
public class RNCAppearanceModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventListener {
                                                                               ^
  symbol: class LifecycleEventListener
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    public RNCAppearanceModule(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
    private WritableMap getPreferences() {
            ^
  symbol:   class WritableMap
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
    private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
                           ^
  symbol:   class ReactContext
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
    private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class WritableMap
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
    private void sendEvent(String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class WritableMap
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:5: error: package com.facebook.react does not exist
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
                         ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:6: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
                                ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:7: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
                                ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:8: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
                                   ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
public class RNCAppearancePackage implements ReactPackage {
                                             ^
  symbol: class ReactPackage
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class RNCAppearancePackage
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                ^
  symbol:   class NativeModule
  location: class RNCAppearancePackage
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class RNCAppearancePackage
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                ^
  symbol:   class ViewManager
  location: class RNCAppearancePackage
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            final ReactApplicationContext ctx = reactContext;
                  ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:48: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
        WritableMap preferences = Arguments.createMap();
        ^
  symbol:   class WritableMap
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
        WritableMap preferences = Arguments.createMap();
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable Arguments
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
        String colorScheme = getColorScheme(getReactApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
                                            ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:83: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
            FLog.i("sendEvent", eventName + ": " + params.toString());
            ^
  symbol:   variable FLog
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:94: error: package DeviceEventManagerModule does not exist
                    .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                                                         ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
        if (getReactApplicationContext().hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
            ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
            FLog.i("sendEvent", eventName + ": " + params.toString());
            ^
  symbol:   variable FLog
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:104: error: package DeviceEventManagerModule does not exist
                    .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                                                         ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
            getReactApplicationContext()
            ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:113: error: cannot find symbol
        WritableMap preferences = getPreferences();
        ^
  symbol:   class WritableMap
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:117: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
        final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
                                  ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
            FLog.e(ReactConstants.TAG, "no activity to register receiver");
                   ^
  symbol:   variable ReactConstants
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
            FLog.e(ReactConstants.TAG, "no activity to register receiver");
            ^
  symbol:   variable FLog
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:132: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
        final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
                                  ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:139: error: cannot find symbol
            FLog.e(ReactConstants.TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver already unregistered", e);
                   ^
  symbol:   variable ReactConstants
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:139: error: cannot find symbol
            FLog.e(ReactConstants.TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver already unregistered", e);
            ^
  symbol:   variable FLog
  location: class RNCAppearanceModule
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearanceModule.java:143: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:17: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
E:\frontend-workspace\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\src\main\java\io\expo\appearance\RNCAppearancePackage.java:24: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
49 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Solution:

**Fix for older react-native (< 0.63)**
Go to android>build.gradle:
paste at the top:

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
```

add to allprojects in the same file:

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
``
```

Comment: for reference check this, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54582549/9579443