# Execution failed for task ':react-native-bootsplash:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

My project does build but it does not run and throws this error

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-bootsplash:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':react-native-bootsplash:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:\Users\ali\Documents\Improdata\JOGO-AI\node_modules\react-native-bootsplash\android\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@5649a92e) before task ':react-native-bootsplash:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported
```

I have tried this solution [Answer 17341800](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54582549/17341800) as well but it didn't work