# React Native: Execution failed for task ':react-native-fs:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm encountering an issue while building my React Native project, specifically with the :react-native-fs:compileDebugJavaWithJavac task. The error message is as follows:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-fs:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-fs:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\lthak\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> > Error while executing process D:\software\openjdk-21.0.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-21.0.1\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\lthak.gradle\caches\transforms-3\47e305173a08682f911db0c5055580c3\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\lthak.gradle\caches\transforms-3\47e305173a08682f911db0c5055580c3\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 10s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: take a look on this similar post: 

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447188/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-react-native